# How to update/delete documents in embedded arrays in mongo db?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, nosql

For example I have a tree-like structure of my data, which looks something like this:

```
  private bookshelf: any = [
{
  id: '1',
  name: 'Im Westen nichts Neues',
  description: 'The book by author Eirch Maria Remarque',
  imageLink:
    'https://img.yakaboo.ua/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/398x565/234c7c011ba026e66d29567e1be1d1f7/7/4/74431_60714327.jpg',
},
{
  id: '2',
  name: 'Der Funke Leben',
  description: 'The book by author Eirch Maria Remarque',
  imageLink:
    'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71-dnZuZ0pL.jpg',
},
{
  id: '3',
  name: 'Books',
  isDeletable: true,
  includedFiles: [
    {
      id: '4',
      name: 'Der Funke Leben',
      description: 'The book by author Eirch Maria Remarque',
      imageLink:
        'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71-dnZuZ0pL.jpg',
    },
  ],
  includedFolders: [
    {
      id: '5',
      name: 'Thrillers',
      isDeletable: true,
      includedFiles: [
        {
          id: '6',
          name: 'Der Funke Leben',
          description: 'The book by author Eirch Maria Remarque',
          imageLink:
            'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71-dnZuZ0pL.jpg',
        },
        {
          id: '7',
          name: 'Der Funke Leben',
          description: 'The book by author Eirch Maria Remarque',
          imageLink:
            'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71-dnZuZ0pL.jpg',
        },
        {
          id: '8',
          name: 'Der Funke Leben',
          description: 'The book by author Eirch Maria Remarque',
          imageLink:
            'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71-dnZuZ0pL.jpg',
        },
        {
          id: '9',
          name: 'Der Funke Leben',
          description: 'The book by author Eirch Maria Remarque',
          imageLink:
            'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71-dnZuZ0pL.jpg',
        },
      ],
      includedFolders: [
        {
          id: '10',
          name: '2007',
          isDeletable: true,
          includedFiles: [
            {
              id: '11',
              name: 'Der Funke Leben',
              description: 'The book by author Eirch Maria Remarque',
              imageLink:
                'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71-dnZuZ0pL.jpg',
            },
            {
              id: '12',
              name: 'Der Funke Leben',
              description: 'The book by author Eirch Maria Remarque',
              imageLink:
                'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71-dnZuZ0pL.jpg',
            },
          ],
          includedFolders: [],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
},
```

];

So there are two types of documents: File, which is an singular entity and Folder, that can include multiple entities, like Files and other Folders, that, in turn, too might contain some data.
Should I need to remove/update some embedded entity, like a File or a Folder, how would I go about it?
I cannot just do, Folder.findById and then updateOne.

Comment: Can you provide shelf schema?

Comment: For a Folder: const fileSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  includedFiles: { type: Array, required: true },
  includedFolders: { type: Array, required: true },
});

Comment: For a file: const fileSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    imagePath: { type: String, required: true },
  });

Comment: self-reference? Or just data in array?

Comment: Data in array. With files and folders.It's not circular, it's tree-like

Comment: the data have not strore in db, and you want to store it? or you are talking about db normalization? or is it really like a tree in database? what the hack....